# Bootstrap Dropdown on Hover Removing Styles

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I'm trying to make it so that my bootstrap dropdown happens only on hover instead of on click.

I have a 100% width dropdown all styled and ready with on click method, but when I change the CSS to make the dropdown appear on hover it seems to remove the styles or overwrite them?

Any help would be brilliant.

**The HTML**

```
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="ion-navicon icon"></i><span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Another action</a>
            <a href="#">Another action</a>
            <a href="#">Another action</a>
            <a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

**My CSS**

```
.nav > li.dropdown.open { position: static; }
.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu 
{
    display:table; 
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    margin-top:-1px; 
    box-shadow: none; 
    border:none;
    background:#252525;
}

.dropdown-menu>li { display: table-cell; }
```

But when I add the below code it instantly changes back to the original styles?

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0; // remove the gap so it doesn't close
 }
```

If it makes any difference the backend is Wordpress.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your css file:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still removing the styles. Very strange

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos i wasn't critiquing nor requested clarification form the author. This is what i did, and worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```css
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .tablemenu {
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: #E7E7E7;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar-default .tablemenu > li > a {
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #777;
  }
  .navbar-default ul.nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu,
  .navbar-default .nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
  }
  .navbar-default .tablemenu-large {
    position: static !important;
  }
  .navbar-default .dropdown-menu > li {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .tablemenu > li > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .tablemenu > li > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 5px;
  }
  .tablemenu > li > a:hover,
  .tablemenu > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #E7E7E7 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown tablemenu-large ">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu tablemenu">
            <li> <a href="#">Another action 1</a>  <a href="#">Another action 2</a>  <a href="#">Another action 3</a>  <a href="#">Another action 4</a> 
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here A</a> 
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link B</a> 
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link C</a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well well-lg">Bootstrap 3</div>
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,</p>
  <p>looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
    Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
    in section 1.10.32. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line
    of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
    Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable
    source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first
    line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like a fairly messy way to go about things.